# Show, that there are only countably infinite context-free languages over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

> Show, that there are only countably infinite context-free languages $L_{\text{CFL}}$ over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$.

I know, that I need to find a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to L_{\text{CFL}}$ in order to prove, that a set is countably infinite. Unfortunately I don't know how to apply  it to that problem. I can't seem to find a bijection, that satisfies a mapping from $\mathbb{N}\to L_{\text{CFL}}$. Can you give me some hints, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to give an explicit bijection with $\Bbb N$. It's enough to realise that there are at most countably many [context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) over a fixed alphabet: any CFG can be decribed by a finite tuple of finite things and so you can apply the fact that there are only countably many finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ for instance, and the product of finitely many at most countable sets is at most countable, etc, and ditto for countable unions. Use facts about countable sets...
If you feel creative you can create a sort of Gödel-numbering of them, etc.

You can also bound the number of [push-down automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton), if you prefer, in a similar way.

Comment: I was personally going to recommend bounding the number of PDAs.

Comment: Thank you! I always thought it must be explicit.